# How to Detect collision in Swift, Sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I was programming this simple space game in Swift until I encountered the problem of detecting collisions. After looking around forums, tutorials, etc, I tried to implement collisions by declaring bitmasks like so:

object 1

```
    enemy?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ((enemy?.size.width)!/2))
    enemy?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyBitMask
    enemy?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bulletBitMask
    enemy?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

object 2

```
    bullet?.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (bullet?.size)!)
    bullet?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask =  bulletBitMask
    bullet?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =  enemyBitMask
    bullet?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    bullet?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

I also put a print statement in the

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) { print("Hello") }
```

here is how I configure my sprites:

```
    func CreateNewEnemy() {
    var enemy : SKSpriteNode?

       let moveEnemyDown = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -1, duration: 0.01))
       let rotateEnemy = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 25, duration: 5))

      let enemyXpos = randomNum(high:  self.frame.size.width/2, low: -1 * self.frame.size.width/2)
      let enemyYpos = randomNum(high:  2.5*self.frame.size.height, low: self.frame.size.height/2)
      let enemyOrigin : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: enemyXpos, y: enemyYpos)

      enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: possibleEnemyImage[Int(arc4random_uniform(4))])
      print(enemy?.size.height)
      enemy?.scale(to: CGSize(width: player.size.height, height: player.size.height))
      print(enemy?.size.height)
      enemy?.position = enemyOrigin
      enemy?.run(moveEnemyDown)
      enemy?.run(rotateEnemy)
      let enemyRadius : CGFloat = (enemy?.size.width)!/2
      print(enemyRadius)

      enemy?.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyRadius)

      enemy?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
      enemy?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bulletCategory
      enemy?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
      enemy?.zPosition = 1

      enemiesArray.append(enemy!)
      self.addChild(enemy!)
}
```

to create enemy (Called in did move to view function)

```
    func CreateAllEnemies(amountOfEnemies : UInt8) {
    for _ in 0...amountOfEnemies {
        CreateNewEnemy()
    }
}
```

and the other sprite

```
    func CreateNewBullet() {
     let bulletOrigin : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y+player.size.height/2)
     let moveBulletUp = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 3, duration: 0.01))

     var bullet : SKSpriteNode?
     bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bulletImage")
     bullet?.position = bulletOrigin
     bullet?.run(moveBulletUp)

     bullet?.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (bullet?.size)!)
     bullet?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask =  bulletCategory
     bullet?.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = enemyCategory
     bullet?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
     bullet?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
     bullet?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
     bullet?.zPosition = 1

     bulletsArray.append(bullet!)
     self.addChild(bullet!)
}
```

this one is created with a timer

```
bulletTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.25, target: self, selector: #selector(CreateNewBullet) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Unfortunately it does not print anything in the console after I see the two objects touching.

Comment: Set the physics body delegate to self.

Comment: @ElTomato you mean physics world

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Define unique categories, ensure your class is a `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` and make yourself the physics contact delegate:

`//Physics categories`

```
let enemyCategory:    UInt32 = 1 << 1
let bulletCategory:   UInt32 = 1 << 2

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
   self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

2. Assign the categories (usually in `didMove(to view:)`) :

`enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory`

`bullet.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bulletCategory`

(Make sure you've created physics bodies for each node)

3. Set up collisions:

`enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 // enemy collides with nothing`
`bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 // bullet collides with nothing`

or even:

```
for node in [enemy, bullet] {
   node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 //  collides with nothing
   }
```

4. Set up contacts

   `bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyCategory // bullet contacts enemy`

Make sure that at least one of the objects involved in each potential contact has the `isDynamic` property on its physics body set to `true`, or no contact will be generated. It is not necessary for both of the objects to be dynamic.

You should now get `didBegin` called when the bullet and the enemy make contact. You could code `didBegin` like this:

```
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

     print("didBegin entered for \(String(describing: contact.bodyA.node.name)) and \(String(describing: contact.bodyB.node.name))")

     let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

     switch contactMask {
     case bulletCategory | enemyCategory:

        print("bullet and enemy have contacted.")

        let bulletNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory ? contact.bodyA.node : contact.bodyB.node
        enemyHealth -= 10
        bulletNode.removeFromParent
     default:
        print("Some other contact occurred")
     }
```

}

Comment: I did what you said, but it still wont print anything

Comment: @ArjunBemarkar then you need to provide better context to your question.

Comment: It sounds like ‘didBegin’ isn’t getting called at all. This code works, but isn’t not a complete program so if you put the snippets in the wrong order, it still won’t work. Can you post the code where you initialise your sprites and place them in the scene?

Comment: Ok I put how I create and add the sprites to the scene

Comment: I don't think 'bullet' has a physics body, because you are using optional chaining in `bullet?.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody...` and if there's no physicBody, then there's no collisions or contacts. Try `bullet?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (bullet?.size)!)`

Comment: @ArjunBemarkar Notice how you didn't use `physicsBody?` when you created the enemy's physicsBody?

Comment: @SteveIves tried putting `physicsBody?`, but it did not work.

Comment: Set `showPhysicsbodies` to 'true'; in your GameScene and see if the physics bodies look normal.

Comment: @SteveIves I did `view.showsPhysics = true` in GameScene, but that does not change anything

Comment: @Arun what do you mean by "tried putting physicsBody?"? You should be using `bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody...` and `enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody...`

Comment: @Steve I had already put `bullet?.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: (bullet?.size)!)` and `enemy?.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyRadius)`

Comment: You want to remove the ‘?’ after `physicsBody` at this point physicsBody is still optional so physicsBody? will cause the rest of the statement to be skipped. If you tried to print `enemy.physicsbody` afterwards, I’d suspect you’d get nil

Comment: @Steve after turning on `view.showsPhysics = true` I can only see the physics body outline for a ship sprite, the physics body outline is not showing on the enemy or the bullet, I will post a new question for that.

Comment: Enemy and bullet don’t have physics bodies because you’ve used ‘physicsBody?‘ instead of ‘physicsBody‘ judging by the code you’ve posted.

Comment: Yes, that was it !! it works when I make the SKSpriteNode not an optional, it prints hello on the console

Comment:  yep. Because whilst the Swift run time is processing the statement! Before the assignment is done the physicsBody doesn’t exist, so Swift doesn’t bother with the rest of the statement. I should update my checklist but glad I could help.