# Collision Detection in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm having some issues figuring out how to detect when a object collides with any objects does anyone know how you would go about doing this?

For reference the project I'm trying to incorporate this into is here - https://github.com/SuperbiaR/Physics-Playground

My goal is to have something happen when the Player and Puff object collides

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect collision in Swift, Sprite kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033558/how-to-detect-collision-in-swift-sprite-kit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `categoryBitMask` defined as `ContactCategoryPlayer = 0x1 << 0`.

you can anther node subclass `Puff`, and that has physics body with a `categoryMask` defined as `ContactCategoryPuff = 0x1 << 1`.

#### Step 1

Define unique Categories.

```
let ContactCategoryPlayer: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0   // bitmask is ...00000001
let ContactCategoryPuff: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1   // bitmask is ...00000010
```

#### Step 2

Assign the categories.

```
player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ContactCategoryPlayer
puff.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ContactCategoryPuff
```

#### Step 3

Assign the categories.

```
enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 
puff.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

You can invoke these collision handlers via the delegate callback :

```
// MARK: SKPhysicsContactDelegate
extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("contact!!!")
    }
}
```

---

Here is Reference.
https://medium.com/@JohnWatson/simplified-collision-handling-in-spritekit-71de9bea6302